# How to export or retrieve Google Adwords data displayed in the main chart/graph?

Tags: graph, google-ads-api

I'm attempting to download a month's work of daily data (broken up by day - see graph) that is displayed in Google Adwords administration page, but having no luck. There are downloadable buttons, but only show data below the graphs, not data in the graphs themselves.
See the attached picture of a Google graph that shows daily clicks, impressions, etc.   Where do I get the DATA for this?  Is this possible without having to get involved with their API? (I need a report tomorrow)

[image]